# Узнать время скачивания картинки, пользуясь requests библиотекой или иной

Tags: python, изображения

В общем, нужно узнать время скачивания картинки. Сохраняю картинки с помощью такого кода:

```
 import requests

 link = http://www.mysite.ru/images/hello.jpg'

 out = open('/home/alexey/Projects/images/goods/hello.jpg', 'w')

 p = requests.get(link)

 out.write(p.content)

 out.close()
```

Может, кто знает другой метод сохранения или же с использованием этой бибилотеки, но главное **узнать время скачивания изображения**? Мне это нужно, для того чтобы задать имя картинки в unix timestamp в дальнейшем.

Comment: При чем тут request? Текущее время возьмите и все.

Comment: @dzhioev, точнее библиотека requests - библиотека, с помощью которой я скачиваю, но мне же нужно знать время отклика.

Comment: Почитав доков, добавил строчку в код: 
     
>print p.headers

но в dict не нашел полей, отвечающих за время скачивания или чего-то в этом роде.

Comment: Т.е. вы скачали картинку и хотите сохранить ее под текущей датой?

Answer (score 1):

> print p.elapsed

**elapsed** - The amount of time elapsed between sending the request and the arrival of the response (as a timedelta). This property specifically measures the time taken between sending the first byte of the request and finishing parsing the headers. It is therefore unaffected by consuming the response content or the value of the stream keyword argument.
*http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/?highlight=elapsed#requests.Response.elapsed*